# Core Data: child object nothing inheriting parent's relationships

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a parent entity of class `SomeObject` that has three relationships:

- `Parent`
- `Children`
- `SomeRelationShipWithAnotherObjectOfADifferentClass`

The `Parent` relationship is a many-to-one and the `Children` is a one-to-many. They both point to objects of the same class (`SomeObject`).

When I spawn a child I add the relationship to his parent, that works as-expected; but I also expected the other relationship (`SomeRelationShipWithAnotherObjectOfADifferentClass`) to be inherited but it fails.

Any tips?

Thank You

*Edit #1*

Here is my `NSManagedObjectModel`; I'm trying to make the children [of entity `SomeEntity`] inherit [some of] their parent's relationships.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing parent and children relationships, which define a tree structure basically, with (object oriented) inheritance.

If you are interested in parent's relationships, you can always access them through the Parent relationship:

```
self.Parent.SomeRelationShipWithAnotherObjectOfADifferentClass
```

if you defined custom classes, or:

```
[obj valueForKeyPath: @"Parent.SomeRelationShipWithAnotherObjectOfADifferentClass"]
```

if not.